# What trigonometric identities produce $\sum_{n=0}^4e^{-j\omega n}=e^{-j2\omega}\frac{\sin(5\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}$?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-transform

Reading through my digital signal processing text, I came across this statement:
$$X(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{n=0}^4e^{-j\omega n}=e^{-j2\omega}\frac{\sin(5\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}$$
I was able to reduce it to the following using Euler's formula: 
$$e^{-2j\omega}(1+2\cos\omega+2\cos2\omega)$$ 
I'm thinking something along the lines of a double-angle identity, but I'm hoping there's an easier way that I'm not realizing.

Comment: what does it mean $e^{j\omega}$?

Comment: $e^{j\omega} = \cos \omega + j \sin \omega$; $j$ is used for the imaginary unit $\sqrt {-1}$ when used for electrical calculations ($i$ stands for electrical current).

Comment: If you break the complex exponential into sine and cosine, then you can use the identities shown [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409) on the separate real and imaginary components, then recombine the complex exponential. Note, however, that one of the ways to prove those identities (as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1214626/409)) is by using the geometric series formula with the complex exponential *as* a complex exponential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing the geometric series gives
$$\sum_{n=0}^4e^{-nj\omega}=\frac{1-e^{-5j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}$$
Now we have
$$1-e^{jx}=2\sin(x/2)e^{j(x-\pi)/2}{}^*$$
and thus
$$\frac{1-e^{-5j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}=\frac{2\sin(-5\omega/2)e^{j(-5\omega-\pi)/2}}{2\sin(-\omega/2)e^{j(-\omega-\pi)/2}}=e^{-2j\omega}\frac{\sin5\omega/2}{\sin\omega/2}$$

[image]
*A geometric derivation of this identity is shown above. The magnitude of $1-e^{-jx}$ can be calculates using the cosine rule as $\sqrt{1^2+1^2-2(1)(1)\cos x}$, which simplifies to $\sqrt{2-2\cos x}=2\sin\frac x2$; the argument is an easy application of angles in a triangle and is $\frac{x-\pi}2$.